# Running exposed wiring from outdoor light fixture to other lights/camera? Exposed nuts? safe/code?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, code-compliance, exterior

After a neighborhood break in, a neighbor had someone come and do wiring so they could have camera, etc. I thought it was odd and might be unsafe, as well as non-code to have wires coming out of a fixture like this and then extended with the wiring nuts exposed to the elements without some type of box/enclosure?

Are these a concern? Should I tell my neighbor they need to bring this person back and do this in a more safe way? If a code issue, can you help me with a reference?

It also looks like there is some type of socket extender on the light bulb, I would be surprised if that is outdoor rated?

[image: photo of the wiring highlighting concerns]
[image: close up on wiring nuts]
[image: photo of the outlet extender on the light switch]

Comment: Illegal and unsafe.

Comment: Is that indoor NM cable?  Or a white extension cord?

Comment: The camera probably runs from a low-voltage supply, which would make the exposed  wired nuts not unsafe, although still somewhat unprofessional. I'm assuming that the 'socket extender' in the light fixture either has a 'wall-wart' plugged into, or has one self-contained, it to supply the camera.

Comment: The neighbor definitely should *not* call back the hack that did this work. They're obviously not qualified (and almost certainly also not licensed as required). They could call an actual electrician.

Comment: Depends on a bunch of things we and you don't know. Might be perfectly legit low voltage work, sloppily done in a hurry. I pity them having you as a nosy neighbor, though. If that's your thing, try being the nosy neighbor that catches the thieves rather than the nosy neighbor that runs around looking for something to criticize on your neighbors houses. Did you take these pictures from your own property or a public right of way, or did you trespass to post pictures of somone else's front porch?

Comment: @Ecnerwal The photo is clearly of apartments/condos/townhouses - some kind of attached multi-unit building. The OP is entirely right to be concerned about illegal, sub-standard electrical work that might burn down the whole complex.

Comment: Not, in point of fact, clear that there isn't a space between the gray house and the tan house. Can't tell that from these pictures.

Comment: These are attached condo units. We were doing a walkthrough of all units with the property manager as part of the regular process. Yes, we are concerned with people burning down each others houses.

Comment: > The camera probably runs from a low-voltage supply
I don't see any type of transformer that would do this and then it looks like the splice continues to the lights on the right.

Comment: Agree that this needs much more info. If you could, at least, get the brand/model of the camera, someone _ahem_ could look up whether they're powered by line voltage or low voltage DC.

Answer (score 1):

> NEC 300.15 Boxes, Conduit Bodies, or Fittings - Where Required A box
> shall be installed at each outlet and switch point for concealed
> knob-and-tube wiring. Fittings and connectors shall be used only with
> the specific wiring methods for which they are designed and listed.
> **Where the wiring method is** conduit, tubing, Type AC cable, Type MC
> cable, Type MI cable, **nonmetallic-sheathed cable, or other cables, a
> box** or conduit body shall be installed at each outlet point, switch
> point, **conductor splice point,** conductor junction point, conductor
> termination point, wiring method transition point, or conductor pull
> point, unless otherwise permitted in [300.15(A) through (L)](https://up.codes/viewer/minnesota/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/3/wiring-methods-and-materials#300.15).

Additionally if that is type NM it [cannot be used in damp locations!](https://up.codes/viewer/minnesota/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/3/wiring-methods-and-materials#334.12_(B))

If Low <30 volts then cables/devices are divided into 3 classes. Article 724 deals with class 1, and 725 deals with Class 2 and 3. Nothing in 724 exempts compliance with Art. 300, 725.3 exempts class 2 and 3 from most sections of Art. 300, but generally can't be in the same box or raceway as line voltage or class 1. So the pictures are not clear enough to determine what class the camera is, but cable coming (improperly/illegally) out of the junction box could only be (almost) legal if class 1, splices out of a junction box could only be class 2 or 3. Can't be both class 1 and class 2 or 3.

Comment: Links are noted as MN Electrcal code, which is the NEC without ammendments.